# how to define the style of a plain html tag to be the same of another defined style?

Tags: css

say if you already have

```
.s1 {
    ....
 }
```

on your .css file

can you define the default

to inherit the style of .s1 from the .css file itself?

thanks
Narin

Comment: I don't know what "plain html" or "default" could mean.  Inheritance doesn't exist in standard CSS.  You can use multiple and wildcard "*" selectors if you're looking for sweeping changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can separate the css with a comma e.g:

```
.style, input, div, .style2{
    background:#fff;
}
```